# C++ ICP Algorithm Memory Leak

Tags: c++, algorithm, lidar

I discovered a memory leak issue while performing the c++ 2d lidar iterative closest point algorithm.

https://github.com/mobilerobotics1111/Lidar_ICP_2d/blob/71ebf795b560cde2865aba121dc387c2759d4f36/ICP_Test1/NN.h#L16
The link above is the source code where the problem is suspected. There is a class pointer nested within the class.

```
~Kdnode() {
        if (this->left){
            this->left->~Kdnode();
            delete this->left;
            this->left = NULL;
        }
        if (this->right){
            this->right->~Kdnode();
            delete this->right;
            this->right = NULL;
        }
    }
```

I tried the above but it doesn't work.
If I keep the program on, the memory usage keeps increasing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically you'll need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Note that using `delete` will trigger the destructor. You should **not** call it manually beforehand (e.g. `this->left->~Kdnode();`).

Comment: Just remove the explicit calls to the `Kdnode` destructor and try again. Using `delete` calls the destructor automatically so the code above calls the destructor twice (this is not good). The assignments to `NULL` are not wrong but they are unnecessary, so remove those as well. If you still have memory leaks (and I suspect you will), well then you have an issue somewhere else in the code. This code looks like you been trying to fix the issue without properly understanding C++ and without understanding where in your code the problem really is.

Comment: That entire destructor should be simply: `~Kdnode() { delete left; delete right; }` -- There is no need for the `if` statements, as issuing a `delete` on a null pointer is perfectly valid.  The only reason why that simple destructor will fail is due to bad coding *somewhere else* in your program.  The second thing is your `Kdnode` does not implement the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), thus causing memory related issues if copies are made of `Kdnode`.

Comment: Additionally `Kdnode` does not even have a simple constructor to ensure that the `left` and `right` pointers are suitably initialised. With the rule of three violations mentioned above, this is a style of coding that is just asking for trouble

Comment: `kd_tree` -- You have this function in your code base.  This really should be a *class* that encapsulates and maintains the `Kdnodes`, and not a standalone function.  Your code is similar to implementing a linked list, but instead of a linked list class with `add()`, `remove()`, etc. methods, your code has standalone functions that deal with individual nodes set up by the user.  This IMO is a poor design -- this should be encapsulated.

Comment: I suggest you go back and write a KdTree *class* that has the appropriate member functions.  The user of the class should not be in the "Kdnode" business -- the KdTree is the only thing that should maintain the nodes.

Comment: Well if this is indicative of the code quality of that library... I would stop using it. Or at least point the maintainers of that library to this thread, it is broken C++ code. I also wonder why they think using `this->` outside of template code is necessary (it isn't)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree but I suggest the maintainers of that library will do that. OP is "just" using it

Comment: This code should utilize C++11 `std::unique_ptr` and then this code of desructor becomes obsolete.

Comment: Have a look at the conditional statements immediately following "the `new Kdnode`s".

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I modified the destructor but it's still leaking memory.
Running the void ICP::solve() function leaks memory. Is there anything suspicious?
https://github.com/mobilerobotics1111/Lidar_ICP_2d/blob/71ebf795b560cde2865aba121dc387c2759d4f36/ICP_Test1/ICP.cpp#L4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://github.com/thithin-ent/Lidar_ICP_2d

This is original ICP source. And I replaced the kdtree source inside ICP.

https://github.com/gishi523/kd-tree/blob/master/kdtree.h

You can solve the memory leak by replacing it with the kdtree source above.
Original source kdtree is not good.

Comment: You may want to open a pull request instead of just posting an answer here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).